# kivy-TextInput with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I'm trying to create a Python server(with Python 3) receives information from the client(developed with Kivy). I tried to use sockets but i got error:
" text input' does not support the buffer interface"
I'd appreciate it if you tell me where my mistake :)

my client:

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import socket


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=2
        my_socket = socket.socket()
        host=socket.gethostname()
        my_socket.connect((host,80))

        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        my_socket.send(self.username)
        my_socket.close()

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False,password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__=='__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

my server:

```
import socket
import db # import my db

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',80))
server_socket.listen(5)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
client_username = client_socket.recv(1024)



data_entry_login(client_username,"dsfsds","dsfsfsdd","2")  #insert to my db

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your problem regarding the buffer, you need to send `bytes()` to the socket. It doesn't accpet strings.
I believe using sockets is so low level and not the best practice here. Try developing a rest API that accepts requests from your client and does the db operation for you. [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) is so minimal and good for an easy-start for such purpose. Getting back to your client code, try creating a `Button` and binding it to a method which sends the username to the server. In your current code, you are sending the `kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput` object to the server, while you need to send it's text using the `text` attribute of the object. I suggest the following modifications

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import socket


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.my_socket = socket.socket()
        host = socket.gethostname()
        port = 8585
        self.my_socket.connect((host, port))

        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit_button = Button(text='Submit')
        self.submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_username)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

    def submit_username(self, *args):
        # Make sure to validate the input before submitting to the server
        self.my_socket.send(bytes(self.username.text))


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Now, I got this error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" what is the mistake now? thanks for help :)

Comment: 80 is the reserved port for http. You cannot bind on it. Use another port. Like 8080 or 8585

Comment: I tried, it did not solve the problem, have the same error

Comment: Are you running the client and server code on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, on my computer, I ran before the server and then the client

Comment: On what port or you binding on?

Comment: Om server binding 'localhost:8080' And on client connecting to 'localhost:8080' ?

Comment: server: 0.0.0.0,8080      client: 127.0.0.1,8080

Comment: Change the host to '127.0.0.1' on both client and server and see if it works

Comment: Its odd. Did it work before the changes I suggested and you made?

Comment: Before the changes it showed me the error I posted the original question, now it shows me this error.

Comment: You think you know what's the problem?

Comment: It works on your computer? So that could be the problem in my computer

Comment: Yeah it works.connect to a random port like 9090 from the client without changing server code and tell the error

Comment: Ok, now the server is : 127.0.0.1:8080    client: 127.0.0.1:9090,I got the same error:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Running the code more than once and it's still working for you?

Comment: So your server never starts. Try printing something after binding your server in your server code to see if it really binds

Comment: Yes, it prints. I wrote print("hello") after binding

Comment: Ok, I found my mistake. But, now i have new error : "string argument without an encoding"                                                                                 on line:"self.my_socket.send(bytes(self.username.text))"

Comment: Use self.my_socket.send(self.username.text.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: I need to change my client code too? because I got error:" [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"     on this line: "self.my_socket.send(self.username.text.encode('utf-8'))"

Comment: your server rejects the entry. checkout the received data on server

Comment: so the server did the job and closed the connection as you commanded in the last lines

Comment: Even if when I deleted the last lines of the program is not working, what could be another reason?

Comment: that's fine :) It would be nice to accept my answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

my client code:

```
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import socket


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.my_socket = socket.socket()
        #host = socket.gethostname()
        #port = 8585
        self.my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))

        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit_button = Button(text='Submit')
        self.submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_username)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

    def submit_username(self, *args):
        # Make sure to validate the input before submitting to the server
        self.my_socket.send(self.username.text.encode('utf-8'))


class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()
```

That's my server code:

```
import socket
import db # import my db

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',8080))
server_socket.listen(5)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
client_username = client_socket.recv(1024)



data_entry_login(client_username,"dsfsds","dsfsfsdd","2")  #insert to my db

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

maybe I need to write: self.my_socket.close() in the client code?